# Does the etymology of the word "government" mean "to control the mind"?

Tags: etymology, latin, french

I've heard some conspiracy theorists say that *government*, when broken down into its root Latin words, means "to control the mind".

I'm wondering if this is really true or not. Is it?

**Edit:** My own research.

Regarding the *-ment* suffix, [Wiktionary says](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ment#English) "from *-mentum* via Old French *-ment*".

*-mentum* doesn't support this claim, but *-ment* might: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ment#French

Only etymology 1 supports this claim. Etymology 2 links back to *-mentum*. I am unsure whether this morpheme, as used in *government*, draws from etymology 1 or 2.

Comment: Is this the same site that broke down "politics" as "poli-" meaning "of the people" and "tics" meaning "blood-sucking parasites"?

Comment: Please include your own research in your question. :-)

Comment: It seems to me that both are correct, but not in the sense you (or the conspiracy theorists) are thinking. Evidence suggests that it comes from Latin "mens" meaning "mind" but came to be used as "a general adverbial suffix" (http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mens#Latin). Etymologically speaking, it might help to frame it as "a group that is of a mind/disposition to govern/lead" rather than "a group that controls minds".

Comment: If "-ment" always referred to the mind, then a replacement would be a brain transplant, punishment would be a headache, and an attachment would be a neural implant.

Comment: Common sense would suggest that an ruling class would not long allow the propagation of a term that put their rule in a negative light. For example, we have a single word and concept "greed" to describe the destructive pursuit of wealth but we have no single word or concept to describe the destructive pursuit of political power. Most likely because people pursuing power had a tendency to kill those who applied such terms while the "greedy" were usually targets of the power seekers. That left a big void in our language.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Government](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=government&allowed_in_frame=0) comes from the term [govern](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=govern&allowed_in_frame=0).  From Old French *governer*, derived from Latin *gubernare* "to direct, rule, guide, govern", which is derived from the Greek *kybernan* (to pilot a ship).

Don't believe the nonsense you read online.  There is precedent that the [suffix -ment](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ment#French) is derived from the latin *mente* meaning mind in some languages, particularly Old French.  Words deriving from the *mente* sense generally have the suffix -wise or -ly, and are adverbial in nature.

But, it is also from [*mentum* - (instrument or medium)](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-mentum#Latin).  It is this second sense that was imported into English.

In English, -ment means: the means or result of an action.  Per multiple sources -ment is derived from the Latin *mentum* via Old French.  [For example, the Online Etymological Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-ment&allowed_in_frame=0) is quite clear on this subject.

Comment: It’s not quite so spurious as that, since the suffix _-ment(a/um)_ does actually derive from the same root as Latin _mens/ment-_ ‘mind’. That connection was probably as transparent to the Romans as it is to speakers of Romance languages today—but it doesn’t mean that the suffix _means_ ‘mind’, any more than the English suffix _-ly_ means ‘body’ anymore.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I agree.  I just couldn't give credit to the nonsense.  I know it's derived from mentum.  But, as a translation . . . I guess spurious is the wrong word.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Better?

Comment: How do we know whether the suffix is derived from "mente" or "mentum"?

Comment: @Houseman Follow the trail.  Which one makes more sense?  Plus, read the link for -ment.  It specifically states that mentum via Old French is the sense in question.

Comment: So procurement isn't getting stuff for my brain? An organ which incidentally runs under the mentos variant of Linux :<

Comment: @DavidM Yeah, via "Old French -ment", which one of the possible etymologies of is "mens". "Which one makes more sense" isn't very objective, because to a conspiracy theorist "of the mind" makes perfect sense

Comment: @Houseman From Late Latin -amentum, from -mentum via Old French -ment. It's the first line in the English portion.

Comment: @DavidM Yes, I see that. Does this not mean that, tracing the words back to their roots, "-ment" is the root? Am I interpreting the word "from" wrong? -amentum> -mentum> -ment, right?

Comment: If you read about the Old French -ment from *mente*, it tells you that this was largely translated to English as -wise.

Comment: @DavidM Yes, that is one of the etymologies. How do we know which one applies?

Comment: @Houseman Reread above where it mentions the English.  Then read what it says in Old French.  I'm not sure how to make it any clearer.  **From Late Latin -amentum, from -mentum via Old French -ment.** It's the first line in the English portion.  The French first etymology:  *Used to form adverbs (from the feminine form of an adjective), most of the time equivalent to the English -wise, -ly.*  Example: rapidement.  **Second etymology derived from mentum:  Used to form nouns from verbs, usually of action or state resulting of them. Equivalent to the English -hood.**

Comment: We know because the words that derive from Old French using -ment are derived from that sense.  Not the one meaning *mente*.

Comment: @Houseman See also:  [The Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-ment&allowed_in_frame=0)

Comment: The first French etymology of "-ment" is "From Late Latin mente, ablative singular of mēns (“mind”)." Doesn't that mean that the French "-ment" is from "mind", at least under the first etymology? Thanks for etymology dictionary link, though!

Comment: The French adverbial suffix _-ment_ does indeed derive from the Latin word (not suffix) _mente_, ablative of _mens_ "mind". The nominal suffix _-ment_ already existed as a suffix (_-mentum_) in Latin, and I have always understood that it is a thematic extension of the neuter nominalising suffix _-men_ (as in _nomen_ "name = that by which something is known" and _flumen_ "river = that which flows") which is of Indo-European age (cf Greek _-ma_ eg "dogma = that which is taught", Russian _-mya_, eg _vremya_ "time", and English _-m_ eg _gleam_ = "that which glows".

Answer (score 3):

In French there are two etymologically separate suffixes –ment. First there is –ment from Latin mente, the ablative of mēns “mind”. This is used in French to form adverbs from adjectives, like lentement “slowly”. Then there is –ment from Latin –mentum, which forms abstract nouns from verbs. This is not connected with the words for “mind” but derives from the Indo-European noun suffix *-men- with -t- extension, as in testamentum. French gouvernement (whence English government) belongs to the latter.

Comment: I don't doubt you, but do you have a source?

Comment: http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/116535?redirectedFrom=ment#eid

Answer (score 3):

The idea to explain the English word government or the French word gouvernement with Latin/Greek gubernare to govern and Latin mens/mentis mind is ridiculous. In Latin we have a lot of words with the suffix -men: flu-ere to flow and flu-men river.

And we have a lot more words with the suffix -mentum as in funda-mentum. Nobody would dare to maintain that -mentum has something to do with mind.